# how do you delete a question that you have posted on this website?

Tags: discussion, support, deletion

Hi how do I delete a question that I've posted on here? Can't seem to find any delete options

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Questions with at least one upvoted answer cannot be deleted by ordinary users.

Comment: There is a very similar question, but with a different answer: [about removing questions](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1956/about-removing-question).

Comment: Willie's answer is incorrect. See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/42265/how-can-i-delete-my-question .

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.